# How to keep the active class in Wordpress menu?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, class, menu

I'm in Wordpress page, when I display my categories and their posts. But I need to keep the class active.
The code below is for display the categories:

```
<div class="rs_filter-inner">
            <a href="#" class="active" data-filter="all"><?php _e( 'All', 'amber' ) ?></a>
            <?php
                $rental_service_categories = get_terms('rental_service_categories');
                foreach($rental_service_categories as $rental_service_category) : ?>
                    <a href="#" data-filter="<?php echo esc_attr($rental_service_category->slug); ?>"><?php echo esc_html($rental_service_category->name); ?></a>
            <?php
                endforeach;
            ?>
            </div>
```

But when I reload the page, always the first class is the active.
I viewed some codes but their not function, maybe because the categories are dynamics.

Thanks for your time

Comment: Could you maybe provide a link? It would help a lot in getting you a solution for this, as your code probably has some js working with it as well.

Comment: Do you think some JS block or reinitialize the page variables?

Comment: Is this template http://preview.themeforest.net/item/amber-luxury-business-wordpress-theme/full_screen_preview/11078987?_ga=1.196389608.550748526.1485373034